# What's the purpose of checking null state at the beginning of com.google.inject.AbstractModule#configure(com.google.inject.Binder)

Tags: java, guice

Here is the method  `com.google.inject.AbstractModule#configure(com.google.inject.Binder)` from google guice:

```
public final synchronized void configure(Binder builder) {
  checkState(this.binder == null, "Re-entry is not allowed.");

  this.binder = checkNotNull(builder, "builder");
  try {
    configure();
  }
  finally {
    this.binder = null;
  }
}
```

I wonder whether the first statement is necessary since the method is synchronized.That is, does it make any difference if we remove the first statement?

**Edit**:Here comes the source code of `com.google.inject.AbstractModule` https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very clear: `"Re-entry is not allowed."`, it doesn't let you to call configure twice.

You need the null check, because this is an abstract class. If the implementation of configure() would call configure(Builder) it would be possible to enter the function a second time, because it runs in the same thread, so `synchronized` itself wouldn't ensure there's no reentry. And BTW the synchronized is necessary for the null check to work, so you need both the null check and synchronized.

Comment: What if we call configure twice?I think it doesn't matter since the method is synchronized.

Comment: synchronize ensures that only one thread at a time can execute this function, but when the 1st thread returns from the function another thread (or even the same) can later call it again. This is why the null check is needed. And BTW the synchronize is necessary for the null check to work

Comment: I agree that synchronized is necessary.And since the method is synchronized already,`this.binder` is always null when the method begins.So I think the first statement is redundant.

Comment: This is an abstract class. If the implementation of configure() would call configure(Builder) it would be possible to enter a second time, because its in the same thread, so synchronize itself wouldn't ensure there's no reentry.

Comment: I think the comment's answered my question.Could you please edit your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @jddxf, Sure, there you are!